# instagram api: we detected an unusual login attempt

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api

[image: Instagram message]

I'm developing my own android app with Instagram API. On my home Wi-Fi, everything works great. It's been tested over 100 times. Today I tried to connect my Sandbox Client to Instagram API through my company's corporate Wi-Fi, then for the very first time, I have the above message showing up. Even after I type in the correct security code, I can't move on to the next activity. Could anyone explain if this is a Internet settings thing? If so how can I avoid this message from blocking me to the next step? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you login a lot, Instagram will skip you and it's normal.

After logging in, save the token in sharedPreference and do not log in again. and use token for other api call.

Comment: Hi, @rasoul. Thanks for the reply, but your answer is not answering my question. The above issue happens when I first log in, which means I don't even have the access_token then. (After a login success, I would save the token in SharedPreference, but during test development, I should also allow the user to log out, right? )

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug with the Instagram API that affected a number of popular apps.

It seems to have been resolved by Instagram in the last few days.

Discovered it was working again this morning when testing a potential workaround.